# How to vertically label the subfigures?

Tags: subfloats

I have 6 images, and I want to align them in this way

(a)image1 (c)image3 (e)image5

(b)image2 (d)image4 (f)image6

Any one know how to do that?  The problem for me is how to make `(a), (b),..., (f)` in vertical direction.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your posting to provide (lots more) information about the document class you use, the width and height of the text block of your document, and any LaTeX packages you may be using that affect the appearance of figures and subfigures.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you could achieve your objective by using three separate `subfigure` environments in the main `figure` environment, with each  containing two vertically stacked graphs and associated captions (and, if needed, labels for cross-referencing purposes). If you want to use the example code below, be sure to (a) leave off the 'demo' option of the `graphicx` package and (b) specify real file names for the actual graphics rather than `figa`, `figb`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption} % provides 'subfigure' environment
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins as required
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{figa}
  \caption{First subfigure} \label{fig:1a}
  \par\medskip % if more vertical separation needed, use \bigskip
  \includegraphics{figb}
  \caption{Second subfigure} \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{figc}
  \caption{Third subfigure} \label{fig:1c}
  \par\medskip % if more vertical separation needed, use \bigskip
  \includegraphics{figd}
  \caption{Fourth subfigure} \label{fig:1d}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics{fige}
  \caption{Fifth subfigure} \label{fig:1e}
  \par\medskip % if more vertical separation needed, use \bigskip
  \includegraphics{figf}
  \caption{Sixth subfigure} \label{fig:1f}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is a figure with six subfigures}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misunderstood the question? With the description given I assumed labels should appear to the left of the images, but now that I see you're answer perhaps this wasn't required.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - I wasn't sure either how exactly to interpret the OP's requirements; that's why I prefaced my answer with a "If I understand ..." disclaimer. :-)

Comment: The answer is good. It is easy to put the labels to the left of the image.

Comment: Since the `subfigure` environment is in fact a `minipage` extra `minipage` environments are IMHO not needed. Just put two images + captions within one `subfigure` environment should be sufficient.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt - Many thanks for this excellent suggestion; I've modified the code to incorporate it.

Comment: One of those rare occasions that I had a not so very straightforward Latex question and got an answer that worked easily and smoothly! Thanks a lot @Mico!

Comment: @CrossEntropy - Many thanks for the compliment! Good to know that this answer is still useful, eeven though it's more than seven years old by now. :-) The lack of built-in obsolescence in TeX and LaTeX is one of the main reasons I never regret having taken the time to learn LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to manually control the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox
{\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\label{sfig:i-i}}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{2}%
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\label{sfig:i-ii}}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{4}%
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}\label{sfig:i-iii}}%
\end{subfloatrow}\par\bigskip
\begin{subfloatrow}[3]
\setcounter{subfigure}{1}%
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\label{sfig:ii-i}}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{3}%
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\label{sfig:ii-ii}}%
\setcounter{subfigure}{5}%
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}\label{sfig:ii-iii}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\setcounter{figure}{1}\caption{A figure with subfigures}\label{fig:test}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. All the two answers are very good to solve my problem.